# Match repeating patterns that are consistently separated with comma or whitespace in golang

Tags: regex, go

I am trying to parse multiple tags in one string literal.
such as `name=testName, key=testKey, columns=(c1, c2, c3)`, and I might consider add more tags with different syntax in this string in the near future.
So it's natural to study regex to implement it.

as for the syntax:
valid:

```
`name=testName,key=testKey`
`name=testName, key=testKey`
`name=testName key=testKey`
`name=testName    key=testKey`
`name=testName key=testKey columns=(c1 c2 c3)`
`name=testName key=testKey columns=(c1, c2, c3)`
`name=testName, key=testKey, columns=(c1 c2 c3)`
```

invalid:

```
`name=testName,, key=testKey`  (multiple commas in between)
`name=testName, key=testKey,`  (end with a comma)
`name=testName, key=testKey, columns=(c1,c2 c3)` u can only use comma or whitespace consistently inside columns, the rule applies to the whole tags as well. see below
`name=testName, key=testKey columns=(c1,c2,c3)`
```

I come up the whole pattern like this:

```
((name=\w+|key=\w+)+,\s*)*(name=\w+|key=\w+)+
```

I am wondering is it possible to set the subpattern as a regex and then combine them into a larger pattern.
such as

```
patternName :=  regexp.MustCompile(`name=\w+`)
patternKey := regexp.MustCompile(`key=\w+`)
pattern = ((patternName|patternKey)+,\s*)*(patternName|patternKey)+
```

considering I will add more tags, the whole pattern will definitely get larger and more ugly. Is there any elegant way like the combined way?

Comment: Please don't use a regex for this task.The [strings.FieldsFunc](https://golang.org/pkg/strings/#FieldsFunc) method, a split, or a scan, would be far more efficient, readable, and generally better.

Comment: things are getting complex if I have one more tag like `columns=(c1, c2, c3)`.
it could be `columns=(c1 c2 c3)` as well

Comment: You cannot write a single regex to do what you want in Go because you need a lookahead.

Comment: If you have the option, make the grammar more strict. It looks like you're dealing with struct tags. The rules for those are usually pretty strict anyway. For example, require either spaces or commas, not either/both. Don't feel bad inventing a grammar that's easy to parse. Your consumers are other developers--they'll understand.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, what you want is possible. the `regexp.Regexp` type has a `String()` method, which produces the string representation. So you can use this to combine regular expressions:

```
patternName :=  regexp.MustCompile(`name=\w+`)
patternKey := regexp.MustCompile(`key=\w+`)
pattern = regexp.MustCompile(`((`+patternName.String()+`|`+patternKey.String()+`)+,\s*)*(`+patternName.String()+`|`+patternKey.String()`+`)+`)
```

Can be shortened (though less efficient) with `fmt.Sprintf`:

```
pattern = regexp.MustCompile(fmt.Sprintf(`((%s|%s)+,\s*)*(%s|%s)+`, patternName, patternKey, patternName, patternKey)
```

But just because it's possible doesn't mean you should do it...

Your particular examples would be much more easily handled using standard text parsing methods such as `strings.Split` or `strings.FieldsFunc`, etc. Given your provided sample inputs, I would do it this way:

1. Split on whitespace/comma
2. Split each result on the equals sign.
3. Validate that the key names are expected (`name` and/or `key`)

This code will be far easier to read, and will execute probably hundreds or thousands of times faster, compared to a regular expression. This approach also lends itself easily to stream processing, which can be a big benefit if you're processing hundreds or more records, and don't want to consume a lot of memory. (Regexp can be made to do this as well, but it's still less readable).

Comment: Thanks so much for being so responsive. I just updated the description to express more my concern cause it's getting complicated. Regex might still be the best way AFAIK.

Comment: I still wouldn't use a regex for that. The more complex your data gets, the harder it is to reason about a regex.  I would still parse that as fields, and split the `columns` field into its component parts using `strings.Split` or similar.

Comment: Basically, regular expressions are the wrong tool about 98.5% of the time.

Comment: BTW, do you control the grammar you're parsing, or are you stuck parsing grammar someone else defined?

Comment: i am defining the syntax for my own use. U are right, I am parsing the annotation of one field in the struct.

Comment: @skywhat: If it's for your own use, then make your own life easier, and make the grammar much simpler. Stick to spaces or commas, not both. I suggest commas, because they're more common, but if you want to use spaces for indentation, then use spaces, and only spaces. :)

Comment: Or use spaces for general fields, and comas just for the columns. Then your parsing task because amazingly easy.